# How to send data to server with socket IO in android?

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin

I want to send two parameters to the server with socket IO but nothing is sent. I connected socket IO to the server and try to send data as this way:

```
val hashmap = HashMap<String, String>()
hashmap["msg"] = "message"
hashmap["friend_ID"] = "id"

socket.emit("request", hashmap, Ack {
    Log.i("response", it[0].toString())
})
```

I use the Act to see what the server responded to me.

And this is my code in the server:

```
Socket.on('request', function (data, ack) {
      if ((!data.msg) || (data.msg == "") || (!data.friend_ID) || (data.friend_ID == "")) {
        ack('input parameters error')
        return
      }
})
```

In my log into the android studio, I see **input parameters error**. So how send parameters to the server?

Comment: can you please share the error log?

Comment: The parameters are not detected on the server-side and in my android log, I see "input parameters error".